# How many order relations there are on $A=\{1,2,3 \}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> How many order relations there are on $A=\{1,2,3 \}?$

An order relation is defined like [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Definition), I know the answer is 19 but I just can't get to it.

Here's a rough sketch, each element $abc$ represent $a< b<c$:

```
1 ,2 ,3, 12, 13, 23, 123, 321, 32, 31, 21
```

So there's only 11 here, I can't find any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $3!=6$ total orders, i.e. permutations of $a<b<c$.

There $3$ partial orders of type $a<b, a<c$, but $b,c$ not comparable.

The same with $a>b, a>c$, but $b,c$ not comparable.

Then you have $6$ more cases where only two elements are comparable.

Finally the case where no to elements are comparable.

Comment: Yes, non elements comparable means that the realtion is empty. We can have $1>3$ because the orders we want to enumerate are not required to be sub-orders of the natural order.

Comment: I got why for the first question. For the case where no element is comparable, is it including the empty set ? (I deleted them at the same you answered)